# Mouse Listener for Graphic object in motion

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouselistener, thread-sleep

Is there any way I can make the oval disappear once I click on it. 
I cannot understand where and how to use the Mouse Listener in this case since the While loop is always running thus the repaint() as well. 
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {

int x,y;
int offset=400;

int i;                 //j;
private void moveBall() {
    double degrees=(double) i;
    double radians=Math.toRadians(degrees);
    double Sinu=Math.sin(radians);
    double Sinu200=Math.sin(radians)*300;
    int SinuInt=(int) Sinu200;
    y=offset+SinuInt;
    double Cos=Math.cos(radians);
    double Cos200=Math.cos(radians)*300;
    int CosInt=(int) Cos200;
    x=offset+CosInt;

    i++;   // j--;
    if (i==360) i=0;
                }


private int sin(double radians) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


    @Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);


}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rolling album");
    Game game = new Game();
    game.i=90;
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(1100, 1000);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {
        game.moveBall();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(30);

    }
}


}
```

Comment: 1)  Don't block the EDT.  Use a Swing Timer instead to invoke `repaint()` 2) The correct method for custom painting in a `JPanel` is `paintComponent(Graphics)` 3) A preferred size should be set for the game, rather than setting a size for the frame.  4) Swing GUIs should be constructed and changed on the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a circular [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html).
2. Test for `ellipse.contains(x,y)`

Answer (score 1):

Under your function:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

This line `g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);` is what is actually painting your circle on each repaint.

If your mouseListener gets a click while in the circle (using Andrew's answer), you probably want to use some flag to see if it is clicked.

```
if (!ovalClicked)
{
    g2d.setColor(Color.red);
    g2d.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

(It would be better to use `paintComponent()` rather than `paint()`)

Comment: Thanks, I used <Timer> instead <While>.